# Update primefaces dialog on show

Tags: primefaces, updates

I'm trying to update a primefaces dialog every time it pops up.
The dialog is triggered by a calendar field changing and the actual call is made from the bean.
When I call it the first time, the datas are fine but, if I close it and open it again, it'll still show the old datas.
It kinda makes sense: it's rendered just once and then it's shown and hidden and never actually updated.

I was thinking about updating it before the dialog.show() in the bean, but I don't know how to do that.
Any idea?

```
<p:dialog
        site        ="sectionDlg"
        widgetVar   ="Dlg"
        minWidth    ="430"
        modal       ="true"
        closable    ="true"
        resizable   ="false"
        dynamic     ="true"
        width="450" height="300"
>


<h:form id="Form">
    <br/>
    <p:panelGrid id ="dates" styleClass="cmt-no-grid-100perc" columns="4">
    <calendar        attribName ="offerStartDateDlg"
                                value       ="#{bean.startDate}"
                                writable    ="#{false}"/>                           

    <calendar        attribName="offerEndDateDlg"
                                value="#{bean.endDate}"
                                writable="#{false}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <div align="center">
        <p:commandButton
            onclick ="PF('whichSectionDlg').hide()"
            >
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton
            onclick ="PF('whichSectionDlg').hide()">
        </p:commandButton>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

This could make things easier

Answer (score 6):

Ok so, I managed to figure it out.

I solved it by updating it from the bean, right before the call

```
public void show_dlg_method(){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("Dlg");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('Dlg').show()");
}
```

with "Dlg" being the widgetVar attribute value.

Comment: Uhhh... but then you can just use the 'update' and 'oncomplete' attributes on the component that initiates the action. No need to 'hide' it in the server side code.

Comment: yes but I should have done in it in the ajax update section. I just found easier this way instead of having to find the path to the dialog.

Comment: uuhhhh if you can do `update("Dlg");` from the server side, you can do an `update=":Dlg"` from the xhtml. The path from the server side is always absolute but you can do that from the client side as well by adding a `:` in front... No difference. Keeping things together if possible (in this case in the xhtml) is always the better choice.

Comment: @Kukeltje True that it can be done from client side as well, but how would you do in scenarios when you are showing the popup from server side using `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('Dlg').show()");` .... Now since it is driven by server side so I guess updating the popup also has to happen from server side, no?

Comment: No, not specifically. Effectively the update is always done from the server (that is where the rendering is done from jsf components to html). The difference between `update=...` from the xhtml and doing it in a bean (=what you defihe is server side) is where the 'trigger' comes from

Answer (score 3):

Some code of what you already have is always helpful. However, depending on what triggers the dialog to show up you can:

- add an `update` to the triggering link/button/whatever or
- initiate the update by the dialog itself like shown below.

```html
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="updateDialog" update="dialogpanelid" />
</h:form>
<dialog onShow="updateDialog">
     <p:outputPanel id="dialogpanelid"> your content here </p:outputPanel>
</dialog>
```

Note that:

- You need the `remoteCommand` to reside inside `h:form`
- You should *always* update the dialogs content, not the dialog itself
- the client-side id might differ depending on your page structure.

Comment: I added some code! What about RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(form_id); before the RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('whichSectionDlg').show()");? Could it work?